# Calendar event, placing event on row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, calendar

Im trying to create a calendar with events. My trouble is how to place the events correct.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

And this is how i wants it to be:
[image]

```
           @foreach (var item in Model.CalendarEventList.Where(q => q.CalendarEvent.Startdate.Date <= startDate.Date && q.CalendarEvent.Enddate.Date >= startDate.Date).ToList())
            {
                <div style="background-color: #bed4e6; border: 1px solid #000; font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px;">
                    @item.CalendarEvent.Text
                </div>
            }
```

My eventList has 4 events, A, B, C and D, my startdate is the currentDate.

each event class has a startdate,enddate and text.

Does anyone know how i can rewrite my loop to place the events correct?

Thanks in advance!